# C2061: syntax error : identifier 'L' in qtypetraits.h

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, casablanca

This has now cost me quite some time, so [in case](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking) anybody else has this problem, here it is:

I have a C++ project using Visual Studio 2013, and with the CPP Rest SDK. Now we start using Qt (version 5.6), so I added Qt objects to the code.

I kept getting this error message:

```
C:\Qt\Qt5.6.0\5.6\msvc2013_64\include\QtCore/qtypetraits.h(523): warning C4003: not enough actual parameters for macro 'U'
C:\Qt\Qt5.6.0\5.6\msvc2013_64\include\QtCore/qtypetraits.h(523): warning C4003: not enough actual parameters for macro '_XPLATSTR'
C:\Qt\Qt5.6.0\5.6\msvc2013_64\include\QtCore/qtypetraits.h(523): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'L'
          C:\Qt\Qt5.6.0\5.6\msvc2013_64\include\QtCore/qtypetraits.h(527) : see reference to class template instantiation 'QtPrivate::is_default_constructible<T>' being compiled
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not Qt's fault. It's the CPP Rest SDK. It [defines a macro](https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/wiki/FAQ#what-is-utilitystring_t-and-the-u-macro) `U`, which is happily replaced for a `U` template parameter in qtypetraits.h.

When I define `_TURN_OFF_PLATFORM_STRING` in the C++ preprocessor definitions, the error disappears.